# Adding data to a dataGridView row in which there is already a comboboxcolumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a `DataGridView` that is populated at runtime with a couple of `ComboBoxColumn` columns. For example,

```
var newCountryColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
newCountryColumn.HeaderText = "Country";
newCountryColumn.DataSource = CountryListArray.ToArray();
newCountryColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
newCountryColumn.ValueMember = "Code";
```

And so on. Now, at runtime the user selects a file to open up, and it is parsed, line by line, into an array.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path + "\\" + choosenFile);
foreach (string line in lines) {
    numOfRecords++;
    errorCounter = 0;
    string[] items = line.Split('\t').ToArray();

    int billState = headerIndex[0] - 1;
    int billCountry = headerIndex[1] - 1;
    int shipState = headerIndex[2] - 1;
    int shipCountry = headerIndex[3] - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < headerIndex.Count; i++) {
        int index = headerIndex[i];
        /*Get the state and country codes from the files using the correct indices*/
        Globals.Code = items[index - 1].ToUpper();
        //If the code can't be found in either list
        if (!CountryList.ContainsKey(Globals.Code) && !StateList.ContainsKey(Globals.Code)) {
            errorCounter++;
            if (errorCounter == 1){
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(items);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, that works great, except for when I scroll over in the `DataGridView`, over to where the comboboxes are. Apparently the code doesn't like having a value from the items array being added to a pre-existing comboboxcolumn. And I get an error dialog:

> The following exception occurred in the DataGridView: System.ArguementException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

Can the item from the items array be shown in the combo box column?

Answer (score 0):

```
newCountryColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
newCountryColumn.ValueMember = "Code";
```

Tells `newCountryColumn.DataSource` to expect a collection with properties named `Name` and `Code`. But you pass it a `string[]`. That is wrong, which is what the error message is telling you.

There are several ways of doing this right, the most straightforward is to declare your own class with properties `Name` and `Code`:

```
class CountryTuple
{
    public string Code { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public CountryTuple(string code, string name)
    {
        this.Code = code;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Now you can instantiate your collection:

```
var cts = new List<CountryTuple>();
```

Add instances to your collection::

```
cts.Add(new CountryTuple(items[index - 1].ToUpper(), whatever));
```

And assign it to your `DataSource`:

```
newCountryColumn.DataSource = cts;
```